# How to embed R Plotly graph from GitHub into Medium

Tags: r, github, plotly, github-pages, medium.com-publishing-api

ChartStudio does this easily. However, the chart is editable by anyone. Is there a way to host the graph in github and deploy it as github pages and then embed it into a Medium.com article? Tables and codes can easily be embedded by copying the url of github gist that contains the table/codes.

Answer (score 0):

If they are public, GitHub pages can of course be easily integrated anywhere.

One option is to create a markdown page and integrate an object in there (f.e. an image) at github.com. You can upload it onto the page or do so via clipboard of your computer.
As next, you give it a name, f.e. stackoverflow_001.md and save it. You can find an example here: [Markdown page with an image](https://gist.github.com/squeezer44/6d029ff77565b31c065f9b377740db1d#file-stackoverflow_001.md).

This URL can be used at medium.com in case you write an article. During your writing process, you add an embed at your article and paste in exactly this URL - that's it.